# mysqli query in WHILE loop

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop

1.) Can you nest a msqli_query inside a while loop?

2.) If yes, why would the PHP below not write any data to the precords table?

If I echo a $build array variable it shows properly, but the mysqli insert writes nothing to the table in the DB. THe code does not error out anywhere, so what am I missing about this?

```
$data = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Cart WHERE Buyer_ID='$_SESSION[cid]' AND Cart_Date='$_SESSION[cdate]'");
while($build = mysqli_fetch_array($data))
{ 
//echo $build[idex]."<br>";
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO precords (precord,Buyer_ID,Account,Purchase_Date,Item_Number,Item_Qty,Item_Title,Item_FPrice,Item_FFLFlag,ccpass) VALUES ('$build[idex]','$build[Buyer_ID]','$build[Cart_Date]','$build[Item_Number]','$build[Item_Qty]','$build[Item_Title]','$build[Item_FPrice]','$build[Item_FFLFlag]','N')");
};
```

Thanks for any help.

** P.S. - This code is meant to move certain values from a TEMPORARY table/session variables, over to a permanent record table, but the loop is needed since there is more than one product in the cart associated with the user/session.

Comment: Yes you can do it in a loop, but you don't need to. Your `INSERT` only uses values from `$build`, so you can just do `INSERT INTO precords SELECT col1,col2,col3... FROM Cart WHERE Buyer_ID=...`

Comment: There are lots of reasons it can fail, not least of which is the fact that you aren't escaping values in `$build`, which are _not_ insert-safe even though they came from the database. You could have syntax errors. You ought to be checking `mysqli_error()` to see what went wrong, and ultimately consider switching to prepared statements in MySQLi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can use it in a loop and

you may wanna add  `mysql_error()` function to find out what's wrong with it and try to fix it or by adding the error to the question so we can tell you what to do

```
$data = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Cart WHERE Buyer_ID='$_SESSION[cid]' AND Cart_Date='$_SESSION[cdate]'");
while($build = mysqli_fetch_array($data))
{ 
    // echo $build[idex]."<br>";
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO precords(precord,Buyer_ID,Account,Purchase_Date,Item_Number,Item_Qty,Item_Title,Item_FPrice,Item_FFLFlag,ccpass) 
                       VALUES ('$build[idex]','$build[Buyer_ID]','$build[Cart_Date]','$build[Item_Number]','$build[Item_Qty]','$build[Item_Title]','$build[Item_FPrice]','$build[Item_FFLFlag]','N')")
        or die (mysql_error());
};
```

Comment: Added the mysql_error but it does not report/show an error - having said that, a subsequent block of code now does not work so the OR DIE seems to be being triggered. I'll try to get something to work out the specific error

Comment: Because this is `mysqli` not `mysql`. You need `mysqli_error($con)` instead.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I figured that out right after posting the comment. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in a simplified form when you want to fetch data from a database to display in html list I intentionally added ***mysqli ORDER BY*** which have only two order *ASC[ascending]* and *DESC[descending]* and I also used ***mysqli LIMIT*** which i set to *3* meaning that number of result fetch from the database should be three rows only

> I concur with the answer of ali alomoulim
>   https://stackoverflow.com/users/2572853/ali-almoullim

**MY SIMPLIFIED CODE FOR THE LOOPING WHILE MYSQLI ORDER BY AND LIMIT**

```
$usersQuery = "SELECT * FROM account ORDER BY acc_id DESC LIMIT 3";
$usersResult=mysqli_query($connect,$usersQuery);
while($rowUser = mysqli_fetch_array($usersResult)){ 
echo $rowUser["acc_fullname"]; 
}
```